# Add top-margin based on height of other element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, height

i have element which have misc height. I need to add some margin-top to other element according as this first block. I was used for this action jQuery height property but it's does't work. Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.post_discussion_header').height(79) + 'px'){
        $('.no_0').css('margin-top','110px');
        }
    });
});
```

TIA.

Comment: Your if-statement is wrong, what is it that you want to validate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong, it should be

```
   if ($('.post_discussion_header').height() == 79){
```

however you may consider using offset height which returns the height of an element, including borders and padding if any, but not margins https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight

```
   if (parseInt($('.post_discussion_header')[0].offsetHeight,10) == 79){
```

**EDIT:** added parseInt to convert the "79px" to 79 for comparison http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

Also you have one too many }); in your code. Line 5 should just be }

Comment: @ukasz-borawski just remember to click on the accept answer button ;-)

Comment: done, once again, thx!

also i'v add > 70, now i have some flexible action... so it's work's better

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.post_discussion_header').height() == 79) {
        $('.no_0').css('margin-top','110px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.post_discussion_header').height(79)` sets the height of `.post_discussion_header` to 79, and returns `.post_discussion_header`. You then concatenate that header with 'px'. Your code will evaluate to something like

```
if('[object Object]px') {
    ...
}
```

Obviously, this is not your intention. Question is, what *is* your intention? What condition are you trying to check for?

You also have one set of `});` too many in your code.

Comment: i have .post_discussion_header witch no selected height. this property set when my title have one or two lines. If it have one line have less then 79px and it overrun to .no_0 bcs .post_discussion_header set display on fixed... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with `.css("height")` this should do it for you ! 
But don't forget if you try to add height to the actual height of the div element, jQuery.css("height") returns "23px" so you have to remove the "px" before you can add some integer value.